# MAMP: Error. Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-5.3

I am using Stripe API on OSX 10.11.6(El Capitan) and it's giving error:

```
Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.
```

How should I make it to use updated cURL?

**MAMP cURL Version**

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/curl-config --version
```

**libcurl 7.43.0**

**Curl Version on my Machine**

```
curl --version
curl 7.49.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2) libcurl/7.49.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Answer (score 0):

The curl module used by the PHP interpreter of your MAMP setup is linked against an SSL library that does not support TLS 1.2 (most likely an older OpenSSL version).

You need to upgrade your MAMP setup, and specifically curl and OpenSSL. The curl library should be linked against OpenSSL 1.0.1 or more recent, as support for TLS 1.2 was first added in OpenSSL 1.0.1.